# Identify user on different sites

Tags: javascript

Do you know how can I set a common id to user for different sites with help JS?
I need so that I could identify user on different sites.
What do you think about using localstorage?
Thanks

Comment: This question is too generic. You should provide some specific scenario may be some code samples that you tried.

Comment: By "sites", do you mean across domains, or are you asking for different pages within a single site?

Comment: "sites" is across domains.

Answer (score 1):

Localstorage is not yet reliable if your users are using older browsers (kuch IE).

The best way you could do this, is to story a cookie on their computer containing the login details needed, (encrypted ofcource) and then basically on every website you would auto-log them in based on the cookie.

[Here is a w3schools link about javascript cookies.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

I would suggest you check this out since this question was marked JavaScript.

**EDIT**

As a response to the absolutely correct comment below, here is a link to the PHP cookies manual, If you want to identify the user on multiple websites, PHP will most likely handle this as it cannot be disabled.

[here is the link to the php.net setcookie manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

If you need to learn about PHP, [php.net](http://www.php.net) is a great resource (probably the best) for documentation on PHP functions.

Comment: +1, but please link to a [better page than w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). In this case, one that at least mentions the server-side availability and usage of cookies.

Comment: You are correct, edited the answer by adding a link to PHP.net's setcookie manual, and a general link to php.net

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this site :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

It's about how to manage cookies with JS :

```
A cookie is a variable that is stored on the visitor's computer.
Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser,
it will send the cookie too. With JavaScript, you can both 
create and retrieve cookie values.
```

Answer (score 0):

possibility is using flash cookies:

```
Ubiquitous availability (95 percent of visitors will probably have flash)
You can store more data per cookie (up to 100 KB)
Shared across browsers, so more likely to uniquely identify a machine
Clearing the browser cookies does not remove the flash cookies.
```

You'll need to build a small (hidden) flash movie to read and write them.

Whatever route you pick, make sure your users opt IN to being tracked, otherwise you're invading their privacy and become one of the bad guys.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is that code box supposed to be a citation? Then please link it's source (and maybe use `> ` to indent and box it). If not, you might be looking for lists: `* `. See also the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)